# Remove duplicates from list of lists

Tags: python, list, duplicates, nested-lists

I have a list containing ~300 lists, however some of them are duplicates and I would like to remove them. I've tried:

```
cleanlist = [cleanlist.append(x) for x in oldlist if x not in cleanlist]
```

but it keeps throwing `RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison` at me. I tried `sys.setrecursionlimit(1500)` but that didn't help.

What's a better way to do this?

Comment: How big are your lists? Are tuples maybe more appropriate? (They’re hashable, which makes getting a unique list – not in the right order, though – as easy as `list(set(oldlist))`.)

Comment: You're adding a bunch of stuff to `cleanlist` based on whether it's in `cleanlist` (which doesn't exist yet), and then saving the value returned from the `append` operation (which is `None`) to `cleanlist`. It will not end well.

Comment: Have a look at [How do you remove duplicates from a list in Python whilst preserving order?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/480214/how-do-you-remove-duplicates-from-a-list-in-python-whilst-preserving-order)

Comment: @BhargavRao: Many of the answers there won’t work on a list of lists.

Answer (score 6):

You're adding a bunch of stuff to `cleanlist` based on whether it's in `cleanlist` (which doesn't exist yet), and then saving the value returned from the `append()` operation (which is `None`) to `cleanlist`. It will not end well.

A better way to do this is probably with an old-fashioned loop construct:

```
cleanlist = []
for x in oldlist:
    if x not in cleanlist:
        cleanlist.append(x)
```

Comment: You could have added your comment to your answer :) It will be a better answer then!

Comment: I think `cleanlist` does already exist. Otherwise he'd get `NameError: name 'cleanlist' is not defined`, not `RuntimeError: maximum recursion...`.

Comment: If it exists, I don't know where or what it is. Either way, I'm not messing with Schrödinger's `list`.

Answer (score 1):

A crazy solution. Maybe It helps:

```
oldlist = [[1,2,3], [1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8], [7,8]]
cleanlist = set(tuple(x) for x in oldlist)
print(list(cleanlist))

>>> [(7, 8), (4, 5, 6), (1, 2, 3)]
```

For a list of lists, use this:

```
cleanlist = [list(item) for item in set(tuple(x) for x in oldlist)]
>>> [[7, 8], [4, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3]]
```

Comment: The result of this is a list of tuples, not a list of lists.

Comment: Or `list(map(list, set(map(tuple, oldlist))))`.

Comment: Depends. Some people might prefer the comprehension. The only really unclean thing in yours is that you create an unnecessary list that you give to `set`.

Comment: Oh, I overlooked the unnecessary set-to-list conversion, that's a second unclean thing.

Comment: this `list` at `set` can be cleaned.

Comment: You still create that pointless temporary list, `set(tuple(x) for x in oldlist)` would be better.

Comment: That's true! cleaned!